# unbind accordion keyboard events

Tags: jquery, accordion, unbind

How can you stop the keyboard from affecting an Accordion? 
Because I use a Netbook, i find myself consistently navigating around the web pages, with the arrow keys.

When the Accordion is in focus, I find myself cycling through the different accordion headers (not even content sections.)

I had a similar issue with Jquery tabs which was fixed with

```
$(function() {
    $(".tabs").tabs({
      active: 0,
        show: {
            opacity:'toggle',
            duration:'fast'
        }
    });

    // getter
    var show = $(".selector").tabs("option", "show");

    // setter
    $(".selector").tabs("option", "show", {
        opacity:'toggle',
        duration: 'normal'
    });
    **$(".tabs li[role=tab]").unbind('keydown');**
});
```

I tried the following code which didn't seam to work.

```
$('.accordion').unbind('keydown')
```

Has anyone got any ideas on this?

Thanks

Edited to add in my stripped down accordion..

```
<div class="accordion">
    <a href="#"><div class="accordion_head">About</div></a>
        <div class="accordion_content">
        </div>
    <a href="#"><div class="accordion_head">Interests</div></a>
        <div class="accordion_content">
        </div>
    <a href="#"><div class="accordion_head">Highlights</div></a>
        <div class="accordion_content">
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".ui-accordion [role=tab]").unbind('keydown');
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your input. I tried it like this... $('.accordion').accordion({ 
  animate: 'easeOutQuart',
 heightStyle: "fill",
  $(".ui-accordion h3[role=tab]").unbind('keydown');
 });

But it didn't work

Comment: @user2950370 Hmm, I tested in a fiddle and it worked fine for me ... http://jsfiddle.net/8F6UB/

Comment: Hey, just checked your code and i think you're right in theory. The problem is that you have a selector for the 'h3' tag, but my headers are wrapped inside an 'a'tag. I tried changing the selector to 'a', 'div' and '.accordion_head', but they didn't work :( ..I updated my post with the accordion html. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user2950370 try `$(".ui-accordion [role=tab]").unbind('keydown');` and see what happens